# How to extend the Mobile default theme for XPages Mobile Controls?

Tags: mobile, xpages, xpages-extlib

With 9.0.1 I can create a new theme that extends the OneUI IDX V1.3 theme by adding extends="oneui_idx_v1.3" in the  start tag like so:

```
 <theme extends="oneui_idx_v1.3" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekits/schema/stylekit.xsd">
  <resources>
      ... *resources* ...
  </resources>
</theme>
```

What do I specify for the extends attribute to extend the Mobile default theme?

Answer (score 1):

The default mobile theme is actually a set of 3 themes: `android.theme`, `iphone.theme` and `blackberry.theme`, each applied as appropriate for the detected device. You can extend some or all of those by specifying `android`, `iphone` or `blackberry` in the extends attribute.

So your new theme file, e.g. `myIphoneTheme.theme`, would start with:

```
<theme extends="iphone" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="platform:/plugin/com.ibm.designer.domino.stylekit‌​s/schema/stylekit.xsd" >
```

Then select the new theme in the xsp properties as your mobile theme or as your ios theme:

[image: custome iphone theme]

Comment: Brian, I can't get this working for me ... I tried extends="iphone" and also tried extends="iphone.theme" with no luck.

Comment: `iphone` should work. I've added more info to my answer. If you've already got that all as it should be and still have problems, let me know.

Comment: I was using xsp.theme.mobile=myIphoneTheme.theme instead of xsp.theme.mobile.iphone=myIphoneTheme.theme ... however, after setting the override theme in the xsp.properties its still not working for me ... the rendering is different but not quite right and my dataView links still not not working.

Comment: Are all your custom resources, from the new theme, getting loaded by the browser?

Comment: At this point I'm keeping it simple and loading only viewPort metaData in resources to set user-scalable=yes and that is working.

Comment: Brian, still not quite working with the theme and xsp.properties settings as you described.   Not loading any additional resources, just setting the viewPort property to test.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. I'll see if I can find some time to check it out myself this week, and let you know if I can reproduce the problem.